# How do I append --active to react-calendar__tile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-calendar

I'm working on customizing react-calendar and found an edge case where for some reason even though I pass in the `selectRange` prop as true to the calendar, the entire range of dates between the start and end date don't get selected. I noticed for the dates in between the start and end, the button attribute reads as `react-calendar__tile` and doesn't have the `--active` suffix, which is causing them to show up as unselected. Is there a way to manually set this? It doesn't append it to the right place when I pass in `--active` via `tileClassName`.

Photo for reference:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the code you're using in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It's working well with me, you can check it online from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sanne-j1tew?file=/src/App.js). Also, you can replace the native class of the `--active` one with yours.

Comment: My issue actually isn't with styling the native `--active` class, it's that the `--active` class isn't getting set properly by react-calendar even when `selectRange` is passed in as true.